# Plugin references site_url vs. home_url, breaking in-folder installations

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm curious as to whether a plugin should be referencing home_url vs. site_url.  The commercial plugin I'm using has since broken most of the functionality after installing Wordpress in a folder vs. root (server change).

In speaking with the developer, he suggested I could use a filter to remove the directory from site_url, but I'm really hesitant to do that.

```
apply_filters( 'site_url', $url, $path, $orig_scheme, $blog_id );
```

Should a plugin, when creating visual items like links, be referencing home_url or site_url?

In my installation, it's basically returning all links with the install folder appended so most of the links are broken (unless I manually hack through the plugin and make changes, which I want to refrain from doing to make upgrading more seamless).

Thanks as always.